# Java - for a class B defined (as static) inside class A, what does B.this mean?

Tags: java

Here is a more specific example:

```
public class A {
    public static class B {
             public void f() {
                 synchronized (B.this) {
                     // do something
                 }
             }
     }
}
```

What does B.this refer to?

Comment: Same as `this`. As the class is static, there even does not exist `A.this`. `B b = new B();`: B.this would point to b.

Comment: @JoopEggen A is not static, A.this exist

Comment: @AdelBoutros But not inside B, or B instance.

Comment: @AdelBoutros But not from within B, this is what he probably meant...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`It's the active instance of`B`. If the class weren't static, you'd also have`A.this` available, to refer to the containing instance of A.

Because the class is static, it should never be necessary to use `B.this`, as simply `this` would never be ambiguous.

Comment: Why would "this" be ambiguous if B is not static? Wouldn't it always refer to B's instance ?

Answer (score 3):

Here, `B.this` is an awkward way to write `this`.

Answer (score 0):

It locks the exact same thing as if you had B as an outer class and did

```
public class B {
  public void f() {
    synchronized (this) {
      // do something
    }
  }
```

which means the current instance of B.